# How to make DifferenceRoot and RecurrenceTable useful for non-numeric difference equations?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, recurrence

In answering [a physics forum question](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=521314) this morning, I ran into really bad performance of `DifferenceRoot` and `RecurrenceTable` compared to calculating the expressions by naively taking derivatives of an exponential generating functional.  A very small amount of digging showed that `DifferenceRoot` and `RecurrenceTable` *do not simplify expressions as they go*.

For example, look at the following output of `RecurrenceTable` and how it simplifies by just `Expand`ing the result:

```
In[1]:= RecurrenceTable[f[n] == a f[n - 1] + (a - 1) f[n - 2] && 
                        f[0] == 0 && f[1] == 1, 
                        f, {n, 6}]
% // Expand

Out[1]= {0, 1, a, -1+a+a^2, -a+a^2+a (-1+a+a^2), 1-a-a^2+a (-1+a+a^2)+a (-a+a^2+a (-1+a+a^2))}
Out[2]= {0, 1, a, -1+a+a^2, -2 a+2 a^2+a^3, 1-2 a-2 a^2+3 a^3+a^4}
```

This quickly gets out of hand, as the leaf count of the 20th iteration (calculated using  `DifferenceRoot`) shows:

```
dr[k_] := DifferenceRoot[Function[{f, n}, 
          {f[n] == a f[n - 1] + (a - 1) f[n - 2], f[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}]][k]

In[2]:= dr20 = dr[20]; // Timing
        dr20Exp = Expand[dr20]; // Timing
Out[2]= {0.26, Null}
Out[3]= {2.39, Null}

In[4]:= {LeafCount[dr20], LeafCount[dr20Exp]}
Out[4]= {1188383, 92}
```

Which can be compared to the [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) implementation

```
In[1]:= mem[n_] := a mem[n-1] + (a-1) mem[n-2] // Expand
        mem[0] = 0; mem[1] = 1;

In[3]:= mem20 = mem[20];//Timing
        LeafCount[mem20]
Out[3]= {0.48, Null}
Out[4]= 92
```

**So my question is:**
Are there any options/tricks to get `DifferenceRoot` and `RecurrenceTable` to apply a (simplifying) function as they go and thus make them useful for non-numeric work?

**Edit:** A Sjoerd pointed out below, I foolishly chose an example with a `RSolve`able closed form solution. In this question I'm primarily concerned with the behaviour of `DifferenceRoot` and `RecurrenceTable`. If it helps, imagine the the `f[n-2]` term is multiplied by `n`, so that there is no simple closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really help with your question as I haven't used those functions until now, and the docs don't give a clue.  But why don't you just use `RSolve` here? It gives a closed form solution for each of the table's elements:

```
sol = f /. RSolve[f[n] == a f[n - 1] + (a - 1) f[n - 2] && 
                  f[0] == 0 && f[1] == 1, f, n
           ][[1, 1]]
```

[image]

```
sol@Range[6] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sjoerd, I chose the difference equation only to show the problem with `DifferenceRoot` and `RecurrenceTable`, not because I needed the solution. See, e.g., the multivariable polynomials  in the [physicsforums post](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=521314) which includes the [Hermite polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) as a particular case - these have no closed form. (This said, I probably should have chosen a non-constant coefficient example without a closed form...)